# excel increment count of numbers but not when cell in range is zero

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Hi Have looked at many options, but none work.
Have column (G4:G53) in excel that has receipt numbers in it, e.g. start 956  Want to increment counter ONLY if date is in column H4:H53 and have something like date, no date, date, no date, no date, date in column F and column G count like 957, no count, 958, no count, no count, 959 in column G.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data. See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.

Comment: Problem solved! Thanks very much to Adnan and Fixer1234.

Answer (score 1):

Your need to create a hidden column to do a running total. See below to note the formulas that you have to create:

[image: Formula View]

See below screen shot to see how the values look like:

[image: Value View]

Of course you should then "hide" the column with the running total as a final step.

Let me know if you still have a question. Please advise if it solved your problem.